# Getting an Array from Flask to React

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, flask

I am trying to move this JSON list from Flask to my react app, but I dont understand the complex syntax

In Flask I have

```
@app.route('/data')
def get_time():
    result_t = []
    for k in range(1, 6):
        result_t.append(str(sensor.value))

    return jsonify(result_t)
```

I can see this in the `localhost:5000/data` view

```
["-1.9661","-1.9661","-1.9663","-1.9666","-1.9671"]
```

In React, I want to set a useState to view this array but my code does not work,
I can see the data displayed in console.log but it is not getting set at the `lst` variable.
Do I need to decode it with JSON?
please help correct this

```
function App() {
    
  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    lst: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Using fetch to fetch the api from 
    // flask server it will be redirected to proxy
    fetch("/data").then((res) =>
      res.json().then((data) => {
        // Setting a data from api
        console.log(data);
        setdata({
          lst: data,
        });
      })
    );
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    fetch("/data").then((res) =>
      res.json().then((data) => {
        console.log('Button clicked!');
        // Setting a data from api
        setdata({
          lst: data,
        });
        console.log(data);
      })
    );
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
        <p>{data[0]}</p>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what happens if you console.log data before the return?

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable is of the form `{ lst : [1, 2, 3]}`. So to use the array, you need to do

```
<div className="App">
  <p>{data.lst[0]}</p>
</div >
```